# Using custom field as 'orderby' value causing post grouping by publish date

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I am using WP_Query. Here is my query:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=test-category&posts_per_page=-1&meta_key=sort_name&orderby=meta_value_num&order=ASC');
```

Why is it grouping my posts this way? It's using the orderby value correctly, but for some reason subgrouping them by publish date.

Answer (score 0):

My query was wrong. Should be using 'meta_value' instead of 'meta_value_num' since my 'sort_name' is text based, not numeric. Big thanks to John Huebner on the ACF message board for answering this one.